# Releasing local variables before return?

Tags: objective-c, release, local-variables

In objective-c, I understand that you need to release anything you init/retain/copy.  Do I need to do that before a `return` statement?  I'm wanting to understand calling `release` explicitly and not use `autorelease`.

```
-(void) someMethod
{
  AnotherClass* ac = [[AnotherClass alloc] init];
  if([ac somethingHappens]){
    // Do I need to release ac here?
    return;
  }
  [ac doSomethingElse];
  [ac release];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: it is bad practice to have multiple return routes which you have in the above code, one explicit and one implicit. you should move the return to below the [release], imagine lots of if() statements that each did a return, that is a lot of repetitive code.

Comment: Why is it bad practice, because it is hard to follow?  Seems like following a bunch of if logic could be equally complex.

Comment: it is not maintainable when you have 30 places that you have to copy and past a block of release code, and when you add one more thing to have to [release] you now have to update 30 places. It violates the DRY principal (Don't Repeat Yourself).

 The better practice if you have a return value is to set the return value in the logic, and then return that value at the bottom of the function, right after your single point of [release] blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to release your variables, however you exit from the method.

It's pretty straight-forward: when you init something the retain count is incremented. When you release it's decremented. When it reaches zero it's automatically deallocated (freed).

In your code above, you init the variable but if it follows the return route then the variables retain count never gets to zero and, therefore, is never deallocated.

Comment: Actually, it's not when you `init` something, but when you `alloc` something. If your `init` method does not invoke `[super init]`, the retain count is still 1.

Comment: @Stephen, thanks, that's what I needed to know.  I understand it better now too.

Comment: @Sam Washburn: You were correct before you edited your question. The documentation for NSObject's `alloc` method explicitly states that it retains the object before returning it.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose to have a local variable assigned like the following

```
NSString *placeHolder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[someObject value1], [someObject value2]];
```

Now pass this variable to a object defined method, such as setPlaceholder of UISearchBar object

```
[self.theSearchBar setPlaceholder:placeHolder];
```

How to release in the right way the assigned string 'placeHolder' ?

If you suppose to autoreleas it:

```
NSString *placeHolder = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[someObject value1], [someObject value2]] autorelease];
```

your code will fail with a bad_exc_access

If you think to release the variable after passed to somewhere else like

```
[self.theSearchBar setPlaceholder:placeHolder];
[placeHolder release];
```

a runtime exception will throw too.

So what's wrong?

The problem is the retain count. The UISearchBar object is allocated yet, so if you release or auto-release such a variable, referred by that object, the retain count is still the same

```
NSLog(@"Retain count before assign to refer other object %d", [placeHolder retainCount]);
[self.theSearchBar setPlaceholder:placeHolder];
NSLog(@"Retain count after referencing %d", [placeHolder retainCount]);
```

So, how to handle this?

Try something like the following

```
[placeHolder retain]; // retainCount +1
[self.theSearchBar setPlaceholder:placeHolder];
[placeHolder release]; // retainCount -1
```

What we did than ? Let's have a look at the retain count now

```
NSLog(@"Retain count before doing retain %d", [placeHolder retainCount]);
[placeHolder retain]; // retainCount +1
NSLog(@"Retain count after retaining it %d", [placeHolder retainCount]);
```

So, we incremented the retain count before assign it (get referenced by) to some object, and - after that - we release *locally* that variable.

That's all.